# FormData request with a txt file, but the there is no file, only its content

Tags: axios, stream, fetch

Using the [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) library I'm creating a multipart form-data body for Axios/Fetch  as follows:

```
 const FormData = require('form-data');
 const fs = require('fs');

 const filePath = 'myfile.txt';
 const form = new FormData();
 const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);
 const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
 const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

 form.append('file', fileStream, {knownLength: fileSizeInBytes});
```

This is how a remote service wants me to make the request. Now the problem that I have is that my-file.txt does not actually exists in filesystem and I'm not able to create it, I'm also **in the browser**, altho I do have a variable with the text that I want to pass as the file. Is there a way to simulate or make Axios "believe" that the text variable is a file? Some like this:

```
const foo = "Hello world!"
form.append('file', fromVarToReadStream(foo), {knownLength: fileSizeInBytes});
```

Or is there a better approach?